# Stop python looking in AppData\Roaming\Python

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

By necessity I have a number of python 3.4 distributions on my system some of which are installed in non-user writable locations and some I have built myself using different compilers and 3rd party libraries (such as MKL).

I need to be able to reliably isolate each of these for use but can't use virtualenv / pyenv ... etc. As long as windows knows which executable to use the isolation is reasonably good. I then use "pip -t" to install to a directory which I can add to PYTHONPATH. The problem is that if packages installed by any distribution using the --user argument to pip placed in a single shared location, and cause me problems.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to tell python not to look in the AppData\Roaming\Python... directory when searching for packages.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to install a package using pip (or even uninstall one), try to run your comand prompt opr powershell as administrator